# How to convert values of a specific dictionary key to uppercase?

Tags: python

I have this simplified dict:

```
{
{
  
    "birthPlace" : "london"
},
"hello": "hello", 
 "birthPlace" : "rome"

}
```

And I want to make the value of birthPlace uppercase: how? I tried

```
    smallalphabetDict={}
    for key, value in myjson.items():
        smallalphabetDict[key.upper()] = value
```

It doesn't work

Comment: 1. This is not a valid JSON, please fix it. 2. Please, explain what "It doesn't work" mean. Do you get an error? Unexpected result?

Comment: **you do not have a JSON**. JSON is a text-based serialization format. Your `mysjon` is a *dict* (the result, presumably, of *deserializing a JSON*)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga **he does not have a dict** either

Comment: Please post a [mre] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This changes all the values of a dict to uppercase, if the value is a string:

```
d = {......}
for k in d:
    if type(d[k]) == str: d[k] = d[k].upper()
```